# How to run code on objects from current context when app is breakpointed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I put a breakpoint in Chrome DevTools in some step in my app. The code runs then gets to the breakpointed place. Can I somehow run pieces of code inside current context?

For example, I have a local variable `profileDialog` which is an object with methods and properties. Can I run them and add some custom debug code right in the context of the current breakpoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once a breakpoint has been hit in the debugger, you can view the object's current state in the Scope panel on the right side.

You can also run code in the Console. For example, after you hit the breakpoint that sets the value of `profileDialog`, once you run to the next statement, you can put: `profileDialog.show();` in the Console to execute that function.

If you want to inject some custom debug code for all calls to a function programmatically, you can run the following in the Console, where `myObj` is available in the current context:

```
var originalDoSomething = myObj.doSomething;  

myObj.doSomething = function () {  
    console.log("About to call 'doSomething'");
    return originalDoSomething.apply(this, arguments);
}
```